# Errors with android new projects

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm new in android programming and I'm trying to create a project, but I always get lost of errors in my eclipse console, like these:

[image]

Before those error I was getting some different errors when creating a project, but I "fixed" them by compiling with `Android 4.1` or higher, like asks here http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html

But then, these others appeared in my console, and I have no idea what is happening.
Believe me, I've already read and tried lots of solutions that I found here in the forum, but they didn't work for me.

Any thoughs?

P.S: `My java works perfectly.
     Eclipse version: Luna 4.4.0
     ADT Version: 23.0.2.1259578
     SDK Revision: 23.0.2`

Answer (score 0):

Ok so you are seeing so many red cross in all of your project? I think re-Downloading Eclipse or get a new copy of eclipse will solve this error. Also try to download all android version from Android SDK Manager.

Comment: I've download eclipse more than once. It didn't solve my problem :/. Is downloading all Android versions helpful? I was told to download just a basic version (2.2) to develop. Then, as I said above, I read the steps in that link and downloaded Android 4.4 in order to compile. If so, why? Thanks for your help!